# Pronouncing a person's name according to our mood

Tags: pronunciación, nombres-propios

I have heard that in spanish, when people usually call each other by their names, they change the names according to their mood. For example, a person named Carlos can be referred to as Carlitos or Carlote by a person. Is it true that the way of pronouncing the name changes based on the person's mood? If so, is there any rule making these changes in the person's name depending on the mood?

Comment: Bit this is true of all the languages I know, including English. I can address my friend Charles as Charlie, Charlie-o or Charski (long story here) depending on the situation and mood. This is not a Spanish thing.

Comment: I know that, but I thought there might be some rules for doing that in Spanish. Anyways, I got what I was looking for. It's called "diminutive suffixes".

Comment: Not really. "-ote" in "Carlote" is not a diminutive but an augmentative. And other variations are often built that are not related to diminutive or augmentative functions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true. I think it also depends on who you are addressing and how much confident you are with each other, since those name-modifications are usually used between friends, relatives or someone you are familiar with.  For changing these names using some rules, you can refer to the  "sufijos diminutivos" diminutive suffixes(e.g. Carlitos) in this [link](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Diminutivo) and to the "sufijos aumentativos" or augmentative suffixes.

Comment: Thanks, it's Diminutive suffixes that I was looking for.